# NPN switch: What is wrong with this circuit?

Tags: switches, npn, voltage-source

I'm trying to use a single source for both output and an NPN switch (5V -  2Amp). I cannot get higher than 500mA at the output, with VLoad about 4.3 V max.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXjhx8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Add some datasheet, schematic ? We don't live in your head

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but the circuit schematic is broken and I couldn't fix it.

Comment: What is U1? And what is Vload? And where's the output?

Comment: Insufficient base current. Put another emitter follower between U1 and Q1base. Any old NPN (BC547, whatever) will do.

Comment: (1) In the schematic you've used in inductor as "Load". I can only assume from this that you're intending to switch a relay on and off, and you've put an inductor in because the symbol looks like the the coil-half of a relay symbol. Change this for a resistor and look at the relay's datasheet to find what value to use.
(2) What is U1 supposed to represent?
(3) Are you getting 4.3V ACROSS "Load", or between the TIP110 collector and ground? If it's the former, I'm not suprised it's 4.3V because you're never going to get the full 5V across "Load" due to the internal resistance of the TIP110.

Comment: @PhilFrost U1 is uC io output (Rpi or similar, with 3.3v / 5v)

Comment: @chaaarlie2 thank you for your comment, and I am intending to drive a 5v / 2Amp max set top box (home cinema)

Comment: @chaaarlie2 in addition to previous comment :
(1) inductor is used since load varies over time (80 KOhm off, and impedance varies when powered on -standby / active-), (2) U1 is a uC (RPi / Rduino or similar), (3) yes accross lad, and reading the ds I get it.

Answer (score 4):

You need, above all, to read the data sheet. The TIP110 is a Darlington transistor, and its output voltage is behaving exactly as expected. The data sheet https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP110.pdf shows the voltage drop (Vce) for various currents in Figure 1. You will notice that, for currents in the range of 500 mA, Vce is about 0.7 volts. Vload is 5 volts minus Vce, or 4.3 volts.

Now. About your current. Your load will have a resistance which you can measure. Measure it. Divide 4.3 volts by this resistance and you will determine the current you can expect. Why do you expect a load driven by ~4.3 volts to have 2 amps of current flowing through it? Do you really expect the load to have a resistance of about 2 ohms?

Comment: I took time to read and find that a Darlington might be what I need if I am not able to drive 5v / 2Amp max load. I spotted this one focusing on the current driven, the load is not constant and output current varies between 50 mA max (sleeping mode) and 2 Amp max (max current).

Comment: But wait - I may have overestimated you. When you talk about Vload being 4.3 volts, are you talking about the voltage from the bottom of the load to ground (that is, the voltage across the TIP110), or are you talking about the voltage across the load? I assumed the latter, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: No the measured voltage is at the load end

Comment: You're still not being clear. Is this from ground to lower end of load, or across the load?

Comment: Across the load, measure taken at diode both ends